# Is Edda the beggar supposed to take things?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Riften I dropped some old armour on the floor by mistake on the outside of the low wall around the market and the beggar Edda came round and asked if I didn’t want it could she have it. I said she could have it, but she didn’t take it. I came back after entering some shops and it was still there and she was back in her sitting position so I picked it up again.
Is she supposed to take the item has anyone seen this

I then tried again by dropping the armour right in front of her and all hell broke loose with vendors fighting each other with shouts of I saw it first, with knives flashing and everything. No one got killed but I have them all set to essential.

Comment: "*...dropping the armour right in front of her and all hell broke loose with vendors fighting each other with shouts of I saw it first, with knives flashing and everything.*" I've never seen this happen before. That must be hilarious to watch.

Answer (score 3):

Various NPCs will react to dropped objects, the reactions include taking the object, scolding you for littering, taking the object and returning it to you, asking if they can have it. The fact that she didn't take it is a very minor bug.